# Ubuntu Server: How to have a lightweight terminal with unicode and 256-color support

Tags: command-line, server, 22.04, tty, framebuffer

When I SSH into the server, I can see full 256 color and Unicode characters from programs like btop. However, on the physical display of the server computer, there appears to be only 16 colors (whatever it is it's not 256) and only ASCII support. I've tried `fbterm` and `yaft` to no avail.

[image: fbterm and yaft erroring]

I don't know if these errors are because the computer was installed with Ubuntu Desktop and then I removed the GUI or if it's something else but i can't figure it out.

I don't want something very heavy or anything like a desktop environment, just the features of the default terminal plus these 2 features. I'm not opposed to X but Ive been told its heavy. thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1025990/256-color-display-in-linux-command-line

Comment: fbterm should work, what exactly did you try? did you do `TERM=fbterm` to switch the value of your `TERM` environment variable?

Comment: I did “EXPORT term=fbterm” and rebooted and nothing changed. Am I missing something?

Comment: read some of the links in the answers to the question I linked, it's a bit more complicated than that. firstly just `export`ing variables will be reset when you reboot. Second it has to be exported before you start fbterm